запись потока бинарных данных в несколько файлов фиксированного размера
Помогите, пожалуйста, советом: как в Python можно записать поток непрерывных бинарных данных из сокета в файлы фиксированного размера?
Например, file.bin_001, file.bin_002 и т.д. Размер записываемых файлов 10Мб.

Читать из сокета, писать в файл, подсчитывать размер записанного, когда достигнет желаемого размера — закрыть старый файл и открыть новый
